# Can QGIS handle EMPTY geometries?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, postgis-2.0

I am writing a plugin and have a postgis table which has EMPTY geometries in the geom column.

```
MULTILINESTRING EMPTY
```

I am having crashes which just close QGIS. I have narrowed it down to the EMPTY geometries. Removing them seems to help.

I tried editing the layer without using my plugin and still have the problem. It appears that the EMPTY geometries in the layer are not acceptable.

I am using the EMPTY geometries as a marker as this layer is a geom "changes" layer where I need all attributes but only the geometries which are added or changed from a similar layer.

Is the EMPTY geometry not valid in QGIS?  It should not cause a program crash.

Comment: Can you share your code? QGIS can definitely handle null geometries, so there's something in your plugin which is tripping this up.

Comment: I made a simple test by updating one geometry `update states set geom=NULL where state_name='Colorado';` Then I opened the table into QGIS, edited some attributes of Colorado and saved. No problem at all so I think also that the issue is in your plugin.

Comment: @user30184: Try your test again. This time in QGIS edit the geometry (move a point) and not the attributes. This is where QGIS crashes. Both with EMPTY geometries and NULL geometries.

Comment: @ndawson: It is not in my plugin.  I can crash QGIS just by editing the geometry of my PostGIS layer.  Removing the NULL or EMPTY geometries solves the problem.

Comment: How can you move a point with null or empty geometry?

Comment: I found a plugin Plain geometry editor which can be used for editing selected geometry as WKT. However, for using that plugin user must first select a feature by clicking on a map. With empty geometries there is nothing to click. Good luck for your development, a possibility to create a real geometry to substitute EMPTY feels like a useful feature. If you have an immediate need for such editor, try OpenJUMP.

Comment: @user30184: you don't edit the null or empty geometry. You edit the good   ones and then QGIS crashes just because the null or empty geometry is in the table.

Comment: I can't reproduce with QGIS 2.10.1 on Windows. I can edit other geometries and save changes back to PostGIS even I have Colorado with NULL geometry in the layer.